# LR vusers using fixed data set like vuser1 using dataset1, vuser2 using dataset2 and so on

Tags: scripting, loadrunner

I have a requirement where in I want vuser1 to always use dataset1(from parameter file), vuser2 to always use dataset2 end so on till 15 users.These vusers would run for 1 hour continuously.
Is it possible to assign vusers with fixed data set so that they just use their own data set instead of picking it randomly from the parameters file.
Shall I put the iteration as 15 in runtime settings?

Answer (score 0):

**UNIQUE** attribute and **BLOCK SIZE** in parameter properties will fulfill your requirement, for more information refer LR manuals regarding parameterization, below is the URL

http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/114350_data_assignment_methods_for_parameters.htm